# Join of 2 pysaprk dataframes and remove duplicates rows from the join

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join 2 pyspark dataframes by 2 columns, the dataframes are:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1["ID"] = ["1","1","2","5"]
df1["A"] = ["100","100","300","450"]
df1["Date"] = [2015,2019,2002,2003]
df1["Date2"] = [2000,2000,2000,2000]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["ID"] = ["1","1","5","9"]
df2["A"] = ["100","100","450","250"]
df2["Z"] = [65,65,65,65]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2)
```

df1:

```
+---+---+----+-----+
| ID|  A|Date|Date2|
+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|100|2015| 2000|
|  1|100|2019| 2000|
|  2|300|2002| 2000|
|  5|450|2003| 2000|
+---+---+----+-----+
```

df2:

```
+---+---+---+
| ID|  A|  Z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|100| 65|
|  1|100| 65|
|  5|450| 65|
|  9|250| 65|
+---+---+---+
```

I want to get the following dataframe:

```
+---+---+----+-----+----+
| ID|  A|Date|Date2|   Z|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
|  9|250|null| null|  65|
|  5|450|2003| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2015| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2019| 2000|  65|
|  2|300|2002| 2000|null|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
```

I tried:

```
new = df1.join(df2, ["ID","A"],how='full' )
```

Which will get me:

```
+---+---+----+-----+----+
| ID|  A|Date|Date2|   Z|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
|  9|250|null| null|  65|
|  5|450|2003| 2000|  65|
|  2|300|2002| 2000|null|
|  1|100|2015| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2015| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2019| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2019| 2000|  65|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
```

Then I eliminated the duplicates using:

```
cols_join = new.columns
cols_join.remove("ID")
cols_join.remove("A")

new.dropDuplicates(subset=cols_join).show()

+---+---+----+-----+----+
| ID|  A|Date|Date2|   Z|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
|  9|250|null| null|  65|
|  5|450|2003| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2015| 2000|  65|
|  1|100|2019| 2000|  65|
|  2|300|2002| 2000|null|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
```

Is there a better way for doing this?

I tried other joins (left, inner, etc.), but won't get the result I want

Also, is there a better way to eliminated duplicated rows?

Comment: What do you mean with better? Less code? Better performance?

Comment: Both, because I don't know if there is a way to do this without getting the duplicates, or dropping de duplicates more efficiently @cronoik

Comment: In this case you can get the expected result by dropping duplicates in df2 first like `df1.join(df2.dropDuplicates(), on=['ID','A'], how='full').show()` But I'm wondering why you drop duplicates only on the columns Date, Date2 and Z. If you change for ID =5, the Date to 2019 like for one of the ID=1, would you drop this line as it would be a duplicate over the last 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, full join is a must, as in result dataframe there are ID, A from both df1 and df2.

So, other join types(left, left-semi..) are out of option.

I don't think there is anything can do for better performance.

for simplying the code, you can just use

```py
new.dropDuplicates(['Date', 'Date2', 'Z'])
```